# kubernetes resource requests and limits adjustments

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, limit

I have a k8s cluster in GKE with node autoscaler turned on. I want to maximize the resource utilization, and have applied all the suggestion on requests/limit changes recommended by GKE. At this moment there is 4 nodes as shown in the image below. They all uses `n2-standard-2` i.e. 4 GB of memory per vCPU.

Memory request to allocatable ration is quite high compared to CPU request/allocatable.

Wondering if any other machine machine type that better suits my case. or any other resource optimization recommendation?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your workloads manifests ? Mainly the CPU and Memory requests!

Comment: Resource optimization can be repeated in iterations until the desired outcome is obtained. Please refer to [ways to Optimize GKE Resources](https://tech.deliveryhero.com/a-systematic-way-to-optimize-gke-resources/).

Comment: @boredabdel here's the manifest. -> https://imgur.com/a/TgZlOj3 
I hope those k9s headers are not confusing for you.

Answer (score 0):

In GKE You can select custom compute sizes.

[image: GKE Custom Node Selection]

We find most workloads work best in 1:4 vCPU to Memory ratio (Hence the default). But it's possible to support other workload types. For your workload it looks like 1:2 for vCPU to Memory would be appropriate.

Also, it's hard to know exactly what sort of resource limit to set. You should look into generating some load for your cluster and using [VPA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler) to get a suggestion made by GKE cluster to be able to right size the limits.

Comment: thanks for this. also do we have to set limit/requests for cronjobs. that run like every 15 minutes, does simple tasks that doesn't require much cpu/memory

Comment: As a rule of thumb. You should always setup limits. Because it helps the scheduler know where to scheduler to know where to best schedule your workload.